# Windsor and asp.net MVC singleton race conditions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, race-condition

Quick question regarding the use of Singleton lifestyle in Windsor, and Asp.Net MVC. 
If the following class is registered as a singleton am I correct in thinking that I will have a race condition?

```
public class UserMapper : IMap
{
    public void Map(MyDto dto, MyDomain domain)
    {
      domain.Username = dto.Username;
      domain.Firstname = dto.Firstname;
      domain.Surname = dto.Surname;
      domain.Password = dto.Password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UserMapper` does not have any data in it - everything in the `Map` method relies on parameters given to it, making the method reentrant and thus safe to use as a singleton.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it would only be a problem if the class held onto some data?